# Saving eclipse preferences tabs vs spaces

Tags: eclipse

In my eclipse workspace, I have my editor to insert spaces for tabs. I save the eclipse preferences file (.epf) and import it to a new workspace, but that particular setting isn't saved. Is there any way to save that preference to reuse it for other workspaces?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can copy the .prefs file from workspace.metadata.plugins\your_plugin into the same path in the new workspace.

Comment: This is not for a particular plugin I installed, but rather the general text editor setting in Eclipse

Comment: You can copy from .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor right?

Comment: Yes, but it's not in there. According to the eclipse forums, this should work http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/297033/0/unread/. I'm still investigating why it doesn't...